# how to get thousands of images from JSON parse and how show it into Gridview

Tags: android, json, gridview

I want to get the images from json and show it into gridview. I see the below link as reference

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

It is working for only 10-20 images.But i want to show thousands of images show it into gridview..

and also it is ovescrolled.I mean if u scrolling up, it is scrolling upto first row is disappering(so

background is appering).Plese Help me and how can i solve this issu's

Comment: what you have try till ?

Comment: gridview is overscrolled  it is scrolling upto first row is disappering. Thank you for quik responce

Comment: @user3899776 Have you used Anroid Query for loading images ever??

Answer (score 0):

To solve this i would recommend you to break the whole image set into a smaller set and every set contain 20 images, Now you can load first 20 images using any 3rd party image downloading library like Volley,Android Universal image loader etc. 
secondly now if user scroll down than download next set of 20 images
logically you need to implement pagination here other wise you face heap issue.

Comment: plese give any example for that;Thank you